# Convert a float to an integer that fits within a range

Tags: python, integer, range, decimal

### Problem

My program retrieves a list of long floats that fits within a range of 0.0 to 1.0. However, I need to convert these floats into an integer that fits within an arbitrarily given range. It has to be proportional per say when converting. What would be the fastest method of doing so?

--*The program is not a pseudo-random generator*

### Expected Behavior Examples

(The ranges include the last digit, so range `0-3` is `0, 1, 2, 3` and so forth ...)

1. Given a float `0.230293857162` and a range `0-3`, it should return int `0`
2. Given a float `0.873102005290` and a range `0-9`, it should return int `8`
3. Given a float `0.596830273110` and a range `0-1`, it should return int `1`

### Explanation

For the 1st one, `0` in range `0-3` is equivalent to saying floats `0.0 <= x < 0.25`

For the 2nd one, `8` in range `0-9` is equivalent to saying floats `0.8 <= x < 0.9`

For the 3rd one, `1` in range `0-1` is equivalent to saying floats `0.5 <= x <= 1.0`

Comment: May I ask as to why the question was downvoted? I don't believe it to be a duplicate since I couldn't find any posts when researching that solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 0 to 1 range can be thought as a percentage so you just need to multiply that number by the range length and add it to the lower bound of the range.

Example:

The float is 0.7, so it represents a 70%.

The range is 1 to 9 then the range length is 9 - 1 = 8.

8 * 0.7 = 5.6

1 is the lower limit of the range so we add 1 to the 5.6 = 6.6

If you truncate the result you get a 6, and if you round it evenly you get a 7.

You can test this by testing the limits:
For 0 => the result is 1
For 1 => the result is 9

Comment: Thank you, truncating the result is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get a random integer would be to just use numpy:

```
# np.random.randint(lower_bound, upper_bound, shape)

np.random.randint(10, 20, (2, 2))

array([[14, 18],
       [19, 18]])
```

Although if you want to use the floats you've already generated, just use this simple equation:

```
# random_int = int(round(random_float*range + lower_bound))

random_int = int(round(0.873102005290*9 + 0))
```

Comment: The program is **not** a pseudo-random number generator, it just collects a list of floats which I then need to convert within a range of integer for various purposes. However, the various purposes requires different ranges so that is why I need a generalized method of converting.